# .NET: embed an EXE file into my project

Tags: vb.net, embed, exe

I know that is strange situation, but I need to embed an EXE file (or the assembly code) into my project, so it can be started only by the application (it can't create the EXE in the filesystem and start it)...

Is it possible?

Edit:

It's not a .NET EXE. Anyway I added the Test.exe file as a resource to my project and I did this

```
   Dim exestr As Stream = Nothing
   Dim a As Assembly = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly
   exestr = a.GetManifestResourceStream("Test.exe")
```

Comment: This is not possible. Why are you trying to do this?

Comment: Not possible. File must be created. Maybe you can create it with FILE_DELETE_ON_CLOSE flag, so it is auto deleted after you are done with it. Or create the file with flag FILE_ATTRIBUTE_TEMPORARY, which will cause the file not to be written to the actual drive if you delete it at the end, but that only helps with performance, the file will still be visible in file explorer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm thinking create a **[RAM disk](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RAM_disk)**, write your exe file/s to it from your .NET resource file, and execute the file there. Nothing touches physical disk.

I don't have a link for a programmable RAM disk API but you can likely find something to manipulate from your program. The other benefit is virus scanners can still acknowledge it for security.

Also I'm thinking if your app is running on disk then there's no good reason why the executable in question can't be on disk too. If you're piping it in over the network (downloading) it or something, then **save to disk first and erase it when done execution**.

Comment: thank you, I'll try that, hoping works...
Anyway I don't want to write and open file because users shouldn't copy the second exe and starts it when they want.

Comment: Was it a RAM disk solution in the end? Just curious. If so what software did you use to implement it?

Comment: I think the problem with this is that RAM disks requires 3rd party software to already be installed.  Which if you can do that why can't you just write to the filesystem?

Comment: If you want to prevent the user from saving a copy of the exe file then ram disk wont help you at all, as the user will see the contents of the ram disk like any normal drive.

Answer (score 5):

Not possible.  This was a core design decision made by Dave Cutler and co when they designed Windows NT.  A process *must* be backed by a file on the file system.  Windows uses a memory mapped file to map the code of the process to virtual memory.  This is not different for a .NET program, even though a lot of its code gets JIT compiled to memory.  The assembly that contains the IL gets mapped the same way.

Good for more than just efficient operating system operation, users and virus scanners really dislike executable code popping out of nowhere.

Answer (score 4):

If the EXE is a .Net assembly, you can embed the compiled binary in your (outer) program, load it using `Assembly.Load(byte[])`.  **EDIT**: Since it isn't, you can't.

After loading the assembly, you can call functions from the inner assembly (such as the `Main` method) like any other assembly, or you can write `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.ExecuteAssembly(innerAssembly.FullName)`.

Comment: I'll keep this answer for reference.