# How can I create a RAM disk programmatically?

Tags: windows, ram

I am not looking for a code that invokes a command line utility, which does the trick. I am actually interested to know the API used to create a RAM disk.

**EDIT**

Motivation: I have a third party library which expects a directory name in order to process the files in that directory in a certain way. I have these files zipped in an archive. I wish to extract the archive into a RAM disk and pass the third party the path to the respective directory on that RAM disk. As you can see, **memory mapped files are of no use to me**.

Comment: If you really consider RAM *disk*, there is no such `CreateRAMDisk` function in Windows. I think you need to look at how to create a driver for a disk, but the disk is redirected to RAM. However, if you want to simply redirect files to memory, then using memory-mapped file will do the task.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Programmable RAM Disk API for .NET?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2402888/programmable-ram-disk-api-for-net)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no API to create a RAM disk per se. You need to write your own device driver which presents a new disk to the system, and make that device driver work with allocated memory.

EDIT (after the OP's edit)

What you are trying to do would normally be done using the 'temp' directory, which is supposed to reside on the fastest disk available in the system. So, a system which already has a RAMdisk will probably have its temp environment variable already set to point to a folder on the RAMdisk, and systems without a RAMdisk would simply take the performance penalty, it is their problem.

Now, if for some reason you cannot rely on the presence of a RAMdisk on a system, AND you absolutely need the fastest performance possible, then I see no option but to install a third-party (perhaps freely downloadable, perhaps even open source) RAM disk, use it temporarily, and then uninstall it. But that's very clunky.

Comment: "write your own device driver" is synonymous to "virtually impossible" in my opinion...

Comment: Yes, I think the people all over the planet who would be comfortable undertaking such a task probably fit in a room.

Comment: Why does the Win32 API function GetDriveType have a return value specifically for RAM disks if no other Win32 API function can create one?

Comment: I do not know for sure, but my educated guess is that Windows obtains this bit of information from the device driver of each drive, (along with other capabilities,) so most drivers return "no", but the author of a ramdisk device driver would make their device driver return a "yes".

Comment: by February 2019, WinFsp and Dokany are more than capable of creating a file system stored in the OS RAM

Comment: @rodix this question was answered in 2012.

Comment: @MikeNakis, Yes, I just wanted to update it with more recent information.

Comment: @BlueMonkMN I believe `GetDriveType` has a return value for RAM disks for applications that run in WinPE or WinRE where the system drive (X:) is usually a RAM disk. Sorry for waking up an old discussion ;)

Answer (score 36):

[ImDisk](http://www.ltr-data.se/opencode.html/#ImDisk) is a RAM disk app that creates a virtual drive from a sector of memory, and has an API that can be called from .NET.

```
class RamDisk
{
    public const string MountPoint = "X:";

    public void createRamDisk()
    {

        try
        {
            string initializeDisk   = "imdisk -a ";
            string imdiskSize       = "-s 1024M ";
            string mountPoint       = "-m "+ MountPoint + " ";


            ProcessStartInfo procStartInfo  = new ProcessStartInfo();
            procStartInfo.UseShellExecute   = false;
            procStartInfo.CreateNoWindow    = true;
            procStartInfo.FileName          = "cmd";
            procStartInfo.Arguments         = "/C " + initializeDisk + imdiskSize + mountPoint;
            Process.Start(procStartInfo);

            formatRAMDisk();

        }
        catch (Exception objException)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("There was an Error, while trying to create a ramdisk! Do you have imdisk installed?");
            Console.WriteLine(objException);
        }

    }

    /**
     * since the format option with imdisk doesn't seem to work
     * use the fomat X: command via cmd
     * 
     * as I would say in german:
     * "Von hinten durch die Brust ins Auge"
     * **/
    private void formatRAMDisk(){

        string cmdFormatHDD = "format " + MountPoint + "/Q /FS:NTFS";

        SecureString password = new SecureString();
        password.AppendChar('0');
        password.AppendChar('8');
        password.AppendChar('1');
        password.AppendChar('5');

        ProcessStartInfo formatRAMDiskProcess   = new ProcessStartInfo();
        formatRAMDiskProcess.UseShellExecute    = false;
        formatRAMDiskProcess.CreateNoWindow     = true;
        formatRAMDiskProcess.RedirectStandardInput     = true;
        formatRAMDiskProcess.FileName           = "cmd";
        formatRAMDiskProcess.Verb               = "runas";
        formatRAMDiskProcess.UserName           = "Administrator";
        formatRAMDiskProcess.Password           = password;
        formatRAMDiskProcess.Arguments          = "/C " + cmdFormatHDD;
        Process process                         = Process.Start(formatRAMDiskProcess);

        sendCMDInput(process);
    }

    private void sendCMDInput(Process process)
    {
        StreamWriter inputWriter = process.StandardInput;
        inputWriter.WriteLine("J");
        inputWriter.Flush();
        inputWriter.WriteLine("RAMDisk for valueable data");
        inputWriter.Flush();
    }

    public string getMountPoint()
    {
        return MountPoint;
    }
}
```

Comment: Having tried both `IMDisk` and `SoftPerfect RAM DIsk`, I prefer `SoftPerfect's`.It had better performance, only reserved 0.2 MB of 100 MB allocated, versus 10 MB for `IMDisk`, and didn't require the `User Account Control (UAC)` prompt to mount drives. Both support a persistent option, but I did test that.

Answer (score 8):

you didnt mentioned the language  , sO my answer is in c# :

A memory-mapped file contains the contents of a file in virtual memory. This mapping between a file and memory space enables an application, including multiple processes, to modify the file by reading and writing directly to the memory. Starting with the .NET Framework version 4, you can use managed code to access memory-mapped files in the same way that native Windows functions access memory-mapped files, as described in Managing Memory-Mapped Files in Win32 in the MSDN Library.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997372.aspx

```
MemoryMappedFile MemoryMapped = MemoryMappedFile.CreateOrOpen(
       new FileStream(@"C:\temp\Map.mp", FileMode.Create), // Any stream will do it      
       "MyMemMapFile",                                     // Name
       1024 * 1024,                                        // Size in bytes
       MemoryMappedFileAccess.ReadWrite);                  // Access type
```

// Create the map view and read it:

```
using (MemoryMappedViewAccessor FileMap = MemoryMapped.CreateViewAccessor())
{
       Container NewContainer = new Container();
       FileMap.Read<Container>(4, out NewContainer);
}
```

Comment: That is a memory mapped file. It is not a RAM disk.

Comment: @MikeNakis there are `Non-persisted memory-mapped files` and `persisted memory-mapped files` http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997372.aspx

Comment: @MikeNakis `Non-persisted files are memory-mapped files that are not associated with a file on a disk.`

Answer (score 2):

**WinFsp** allows you to define your own file system programmatically, using plain c++ or also dotNet C#. **The example project is a file system persisted in OS RAM memory**. You may also take a look at **Dokany**.

https://github.com/billziss-gh/winfsp

https://github.com/dokan-dev/dokany