# Write Memory stream directly to Excel or Image File

Tags: c#, encryption

I have a code snippet that has a memory stream that contains excel data and sometimes image data.

```
CryptoStream cs = new CryptoStream(fsCrypt, AES.CreateDecryptor(), CryptoStreamMode.Read);
     MemoryStream msOut = new MemoryStream();

     int read;
     byte[] buffer = new byte[1048576];
    
     try
       {
           while ((read = cs.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0)
           {
               msOut.Write(buffer, 0, read);
           }
    
                 var temp = filename.Split('.');
                Debug.Log(temp[0]+"."+temp[1]);
                filename = temp[0] + "." + temp[1]; 
                File.WriteAllBytes(filename, msOut.ToArray());  
    
    
                return filename;
    
            }
```

In order to view the memory stream in the readable format first, I have to write it on the hard drive then I open it with native software like MS Excel or image viewer.

```
 File.WriteAllBytes(filename, msOut.ToArray());
```

My question is that is there any way available to open it directly from the memory instead first saving on the disk?

Comment: You have a `MemoryStream` that contains that data because you copied it from what appears to be another `Stream`: `cs`. Why not open a `FileStream` and use `cs.CopyTo(fs);`?

Comment: Sorry i didn't get your point. Let me explain, the file is presented on hard drive already but it is in encrpyted format. I am decrypting on runtime and want to show its content from the memory. I mean i don't to re-write decrpted file on the hard drive. Just want to directly show decrypted data from the memory

Comment: Oh, so you're not asking about the redundant step of storing it in `MemoryStream`? I see. I would think you would probably need something like a RAM drive.

Comment: Actually i am able to decrypt and open it using application.openurl method. But this method required files in the hard drive. And if it is available in the drive then, anyone can see it. I am looking for direct way to open it

Comment: Yeah, so you'd probably need a RAM disk. Perhaps you could start by looking at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8692521/how-can-i-create-a-ram-disk-programmatically).