# Create local disk that when accessed sends a http request

Tags: windows, virtual-disk

So, my issue is as follows:

I need to create an .exe file that, when ran:

1: Creates a local disk in the Computer(say S)-this absolutely 100% needs to be considered local by the system.

2: Whenever S:{idlist} is accessed, create http request to a server: www.server.com:{idlist}. Response is in JSON. Return this response to whatever running app accessed S:{idlist}.

If possible guide me to what i should do to achieve this.(From what i know, it's doable in .NET, with C# or C++, tho i'm not sure exactly how).Any tips, documentation would be perfect.

Thank you and sorry for my english, not my native language and i'm only 15 y/o.

Comment: It sounds like you would be better off [writing a Windows Service](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zt39148a(v=vs.110).aspx). Otherwise you are trying to subvert the file system for a purpose for which it was not intended. I suppose you could use a [RAMdisk](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2402888/programmable-ram-disk-api-for-net) and use a [FileSystemWatcher](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesystemwatcher(v=vs.110).aspx) to detect writes to it...

Comment: ... It will be rather inefficient to do that, and your `idlist` will be limited to characters which are [legal filenames](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365247(v=vs.85).aspx).